# Return a base-class object from a derived-class object

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

I'm aware that Perl is not statically typed when I want to apply this mechanism to a Perl object of a derived class:

Say I have a base class `B` and a derived class `D` inheriting from `B`.
Also I have an object `$obj` that holds a `D` object.
A function `Bf()` is expecting a parameter of type `B`.

Obviously (by the rules of polymorphism) I can pass `$obj` to `Bf()` like `Bf($obj)`, but unlike to a static-typed language `Bf()` will see the whole `D` object (and not just the elements of `B`).

Is there a (rather clean and simple) solution for this problem in Perl? The solution should "hide" the attributes (and methods) a `B` does not have from `D` in `Bf()`, not restricting modifications of the original `B` (which is `D` actually).

### Adult Programmers only (added 2020-03-06)

OK, people wanted a more concrete description.
Unfortunately (as pointed out) the original program is highly complex and uses reflection-like mechanisms to generate getters, setters and formatters automatically, to I really **can't** give a minimum working example here, because it would not be minimal.

First I have a class `MessageHandler` that handle messages (no surprise!).
Then I have a function `log_message($$$)` that expects (among others) a `MessageHandler` object as first argument.

Then I have this hierarchy of classes (it's much more complex in reality):

```
MessageHandler
ControlMessageHandler (ISA: MessageHandler)
ControlMessageResponseHandler (ISA: ControlMessageHandler)
```

Now if `log_message` wants a `MessageHandler` I can pass a `ControlMessageResponseHandler` as it conforms to `MessageHandler`.
But doing so exposes all the attributes of `ControlMessageResponseHandler` to `log_message` that are non-existent in `MessageHandler`.

The danger is that `log_message` might (by mistake) access an attribute of `ControlMessageResponseHandler` that is not present in `MessageHandler`. To prevent errors I'd like to prevent that, or at least get some warning (like I would get in a statically-typed language as Eiffel).

### Dirty Details inside

Just in case it matters, I'll sketch how my array objects are built (a lot of extra code would be needed for a working example):

First the array indices are allocated automatically like this:

```
use constant I_VERBOSITY    => IS_NEXT->(); # verbosity level
use constant I_TAG          => IS_NEXT->(); # additional tag
use constant I_TAG_STACK    => IS_NEXT->(); # tag stack
use constant I_MSG_DEBUG    => IS_NEXT->(); # handler for debug messages
...
use constant I_LAST         => IS_LAST->(); # last index (must be last)
```

`I_LAST` is needed for inheritance.
The attributes are defines like this:

```
use constant ATTRIBUTES => (
    ['verbosity', I_VERBOSITY, undef],
    ['tag', I_TAG, \&Class::_format_string],
    ['tag_stack', I_TAG_STACK, undef],
    ['msg_debug', I_MSG_DEBUG, \&Class::_format_code],
...
);
```

The definition contains a hint how to format each attribute.
This information is used to set up formatters to format each attribute like this:

```
use constant FORMATTERS =>
    (map { Class::_attribute_string($_->[0], $_->[1], undef, $_->[2]) }
     ATTRIBUTES);           # attribute formatters
```

Getters and setters are automatically defined like this:

```
BEGIN {
    foreach (ATTRIBUTES) {
    Class::_assign_gs_ai(__PACKAGE__, $_->[0], $_->[1]);
    }
}
```

The constructor would use the following lines:

```
my $self = [];

$#$self = I_LAST;
$self->[I_VERBOSITY] = $verbosity;
...
```

And finally my object print routine goes like this:

```
sub as_string($)
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $a_sep = ', ';

    return join($a_sep, map { $_->($self, $a_sep) } FORMATTERS);
}
```

With inheritance it looks like this:

```
sub as_string($)
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $a_sep = ', ';

    return join($a_sep, $self->SUPER::as_string(),
        map { $_->($self, $a_sep) } FORMATTERS);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is. Using a subclass in the same way you would use its parent class is very common, and not generally a problem.

Comment: A minimal working example of what you want to actually accomplish would be helpful. What do your constructors look like? Why does `Bf()` need "just the elements of `B`", and what exactly do you mean by "elements"?

Comment: "_A function `Bf()` is **expecting** a parameter of type `B`._" (my emphasis)" -- That can only mean the code in that function is written for object of `B`, since you can't write code to dynamically bind calls in Perl.  So the one thing you can do is to implement that in a way -- to manually check for what object you got, and if it's from `D` instead of `B`, call parent's method.  Or, better, design code so that there is no need for this.

Comment: But, if it matters for `Bf()` whether it gets an object of `B` or `D` (since the methods it uses differ between these classes) -- as it seems to be the case, or otherwise there'd be no question ... then it's a plain error to send it a `D` object, no?

Comment: @Possum "elements" is "attributes + methods" in general speak.

Comment: Maybe let's point out that one of the issues I'm struggling with is that every class in my system has an `as_string` method, and when `Bf()` would print its "`B`" it would print all the other attributes that a `B` does not have. Because they are there.

Comment: OK guys: There's some confusion what I want to do, and the code I'm talking about is highly complex in reality. Probably it's not perfect as I'm still modelling the code from a minimum skeleton to the final destination. -- so hold; I'll try to provide more concrete lines when I find time to do so, but the code I'm talking about is more than 5000 lines.

Comment: A few comments after the code is shown. I take it that it's about `as_string` sub. (1) It seems that an object is always the first argument -- then make it a method?  Then there's no question, each class has its own. (2)  If that in fact _is a method_ then the prototype is misleading (it's ignored for a method), and I don't see grounds for the question since you can craft derived class's version to do what you want  (3) With this much complexity I'd definitely simplify, so take the needed object or call it an error. /// I'd say you got plenty on this page to make your decisions

Comment: @zdim on "no language can give you that. ": Every statically-typed language (e.g. Eiffel) does that. So it seems the actual impossibility to specify the expected "static" object type in Perl makes it impossible to get what I want. The `can`-thing smells like "interfaces", and it's not quite what I'm looking for. And it's *not* an error to get a `D` for `Bf()`: It's polymorphism or dynamic binding. I also do not see what's wrong with the prototype of `as_string($)` if it's the function to return the object as string.

Comment: The edit I quoted asks for an object to lose the added bits but to keep the ones it changed from its parent, I referred to that; granted, I don't know all tools out there, but "dynamic binding" as commonly understood gives either this one or that one, not a part of this one but not quite that one either.  In Perl we don't get "dynamic binding" at all; if you really want it you have to implement it, and if you want to be able to tell which methods are added you _need_ `can` or some such. As for prototypes, they are just ignored for methods, that's all I meant.

Comment: @U.Windl the prototype ([in Perl terms](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes)) on `as_string($)` is the `($)`; it specifies that the function accepts a single scalar argument. It is only useful for subroutines used as _functions_, so you can use it unambiguously in certain contexts, i.e., `my @list = ( as_string $x, as_string $y );` is interpreted as `my @list = ( as_string($x), as_string($y) );` instead of `my @list = ( as_string($x, as_string($y)) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there doesn't seem to be a perfect solution, temporary "re-blessing" the object seems to get quite close to what is asked for:

```perl
sub Bf($) # expects a "B" object (or descendant of "B" (like "D"))
{
    my $B = shift;
    my $type = ref($B);  # save original type

    die "unexpected type $type" unless ($B->isa('B'));
    bless $B, 'B';       # restrict to "B"'s features
    $B->whatever(...);
    #...
    bless $B, $type;     # restore original type
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. I think that unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately, depending on how you look at it), Perl does not have a very robust object system, and you   you do have to write explicit code to handle these types of polymorphism. Thank you for updating your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your problem is, although I think you took the long way to say "I have a function that expects a B object, and I want to pass it a D object."

If you only want objects of a certain exact type, don't accept anything else:

```
use Carp qw(croak);
sub Bf {
    croak "Bad object! I only like B" unless ref $_[0] eq 'B';
    ...
    }
```

But, that's a bad idea. A derived class should be just as good as the base class. The clean solution is to not care what type you get.

```
sub Bf {
    croak "Bad object! Doesn't respond to foo!" unless $_[0]->can('foo');
    ...
    }
```

Since this `Bf` method works with the base class, why would it look for something in some derived class it didn't know about? If the derived class has changed the interface and no longer acts like its parent, then maybe it's isn't a good fit for inheritance. There are many problems like this that are solved by a different architecture.

I think you'll have to come up with a concrete example where the derived class wouldn't work.

Comment: No I expect `Bf` to well-behave, but it's just tempting when seeing the other attributes (and a programming error) to use any of those.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like for some reason you need your `D` object to behave like a `B` object, but at the same time *not* like a `D` object. As the existing answers and comments indicate, it's a very common to use a sub-class where the base class is expected, and most algorithms shouldn't care whether what you actually passed is `D` or `B`. The only reason I can think of why you would want otherwise is that `D` overrides (redefines) some methods in an incompatible way, and you want the methods from `B`  instead.

```
package Dog;
sub new {
  my ($class, %args) = @_;
  return bless \%args, $class;
}
sub bark { print "Bark!\n"; }

package Dingo;
use parent 'Dog';
sub bark { print "...\n"; }

package main;
my $dingo = Dingo->new;
$dingo->bark; # "..."
```

(n.b., I've left off the recommended `use strict;` and `use warnings;` for terseness, they should be used in all packages)

You may be aware from reading `perldoc perlootut` and `perldoc perlobj` that an object in Perl is just a `bless`ed reference of some sort; in the example above, we use a hash reference. If you are trying to get the "attributes" that only exist in `B`, I think you would have to write some sort of translation method. But, if you care about the methods that exist in `B`, all you have to do is re-`bless` it into the parent class.

```
my $dingo = Dingo->new;
$dingo->bark; # "..."
bless $dingo, "Dog";
$dingo->bark; # "Bark!"
```

Note that `bless` does not return a new reference, but modifies that reference in-place; if you want it to behave like a `Dingo` again, you have to `bless` it back.

Perhaps more conveniently you can define a method to create a copy for you and bless it into the appropriate class:

```
package Dog;
sub as_dog {
  my ($self) = @_;

  # The {} below create a shallow copy, i.e., a new reference
  return bless { %{$self} }, __PACKAGE__;
}

#...
package main;
my $dingo = Dingo->new;
$dingo->bark; # ...
$dingo->as_dog->bark; # Bark!
$dingo->bark; # ...
```

Comment: Actually as my objects use ARRAYs not HASHes I could easily either (a) "slice away" the descendant's extra attributes, but that could (in theory) make some overloaded method fail, or (b) make a copy of the slice and work with that, which in turn has the problem that no object modifications can be done to the original object.